# How do I re-dock solution explorer and properties window in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

When I first started Visual Studio 2017 the Solution Explorer was docked to the right. I undocked it since then and now want to dock it back on the right but have had no success. When I drag it over to the right I get no response from Visual Studio that it will dock on the right. There is a dock icon at the top of the Solution Explorer but when I click that it docks into the document tabs at the top which is not what I want. I would like it docked at the right so it automatically rolls out to use when my mouse point is in that area and it rolls back into the right side when I don't need it.

How do I get the Solution explorer to dock to the right like it was when Visual Studio was first started? I would like to do the same for the properties window. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 34):

In Visual Studio IDE, click on Window -> Reset Window Layout -> Yes (Are you sure question). This will put the solution explorer back to the default layout docked to the right. It will also dock any other windows to their original position like Server Explorer, ToolBox, Text Explorer, Output, Error List to the left.

Comment: Thank you!. This solved my problem with a rogue floating tool window above the top of my screen in VS 2019. I was unable to get to the window caption to re-dock it.

Comment: This is strange, resetting puts my Solution Explorer to the left instead of the right. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

If you right click on a window, the auto-hide feature should also fix your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Making the window auto-hide will add it to the right sidebar where it will open on click and automatically close once click somewhere else. Right click on top bar of Solution-Explorer window to select Auto-Hide

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to reset my entire layout, so I found another way.  Undock both the Solution Explorer and the Properties.  Then you can drag the Properties onto the Solution Explorer.  It will pop to the bottom half.  Then you can redock the combined window where it was before.